# Plotly : subplot layout in the online tool

Tags: plotly

I'm using plotly online (free). I would like to create two subplots side by side.

The documentation for this is here https://help.plot.ly/subplot-layouts/, but it's out-of-date: the button "Subplot & Multiple Axes" doesn't exist anymore.

And I can't find anything under the "subplot" tab.

How do I create two subplots (one trace on each subplot) with plotly?

Comment: If you know Python, you can use code from examples [here](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create your two traces (and bind them to data on the grid), make sure to change at least one of the "Axes to Use" on one of them. Than they will both appear on Subplots panel. In the second subplot - set X Overlay and Y Overlay as None, than your two subplots can be completely independent and you can move them around using that rectangle control.

Comment: Almost trivial! I can see them both on Subplots panel but I'm unable to move around the second subplot (and when I move around the first one, both traces move). Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh yes! In subplots panel you should select Overlay: None